# Using OpenCV cv::kmeans() with one-dimensional input

Tags: c++, opencv, k-means

Although the [python tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_ml/py_kmeans/py_kmeans_opencv/py_kmeans_opencv.html) uses one-dimensional data, I cannot do the same with the C++ interface:

```
int size=100;
std::vector<float> data(size);
for (size_t i = 0; i < size ; i++)
{
    data[i] = (float)i; //placeholder
}
std::vector<int> labels;
std::vector<float> centers;
cv::kmeans(data, 3, labels,
    cv::TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER+CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 10, 0.1),
    3, cv::KMEANS_PP_CENTERS, centers);
```

This fails with an internal assertion since cv::kmeans expects the input to be two-dimensional. `CV_Assert(N>=K)` fails since K is 3 and N is 1. What is my mistake?

Comment: what is 'strengths' ? also, N is the number of elems in the input Mat for a row-vector. i'm just guessing, but you probably got the shape wrong. strengths.reshape(1,1) should make it a n-elem, 1 row input

Comment: renamed it to "data". The input is a std::vector (which should normally be fine since OpenCV internally knows how to handle vectors as inputs). But it converts it to a (1 x data.size() ) matrix with one channel. And this is leads to an exception since kmeans excepts a 2-channel input.

Comment: why not use a Mat data instead of the vector<float> ?

Comment: The assertion (N>=K) just makes sure that you have at least as much samples as the number of cluster you want to compute. Your problem is that passing vector to kmeans instead of cv::Mat leads to a wrong computation of N, as @Xocoatzin says in his answer

Comment: @"why not use a Mat?": I find vectors much easier to understand: you just see directly what is stored when you hover over the object in your IDE. A matrix is not clealy typed.  And usually, OpenCV can deal with vectors. In the end (as the answers suggested) I used a matrix. But I believe this is an OpenCV bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**:

I've just checked the source, it reads:

```
//...
bool isrow = data.rows == 1 && data.channels() > 1; // MORE THAN ONE CHANNEL
int N = !isrow ? data.rows : data.cols; 
//...

//...
CV_Assert( N >= K );
```

So, if you have your data in a single row, you need to have more than a single channel in your input matrix and more columns than `K`.

---

A quick workaround: [reshape](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-reshape) your matrix before calling `kmeans`

It doesn't copy any data, just changes the dimensions of the matrix. So if you have:

```
[12345678] // mat 1 x 8
```

After you reshape with 2 rows:

```
[1234| // a mat 2 x 4
|5678]
```

You should be able to call `kmeans` then. (Don't forget to reshape back)

Comment: I pushed a [fix](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/pull/5230) to OpenCV and it got merged for version 3.1

Answer (score 4):

The trouble is that when you pass a vector to something that takes an InputArray, when getMat() gets called on that InputArray a Mat with 1 row gets created. But that won't work in this case for the reason Xocoatzin pointed out in the source. You obviously can't reshape a vector, although that has been suggested. If your input is a vector, and you can't change that, you need to explicitly convert the vector into a 1 column Mat, like below.

```
int size=100;
std::vector<float> data(size);
for (size_t i = 0; i < size ; i++)
{
    data[i] = (float)i; //placeholder
}

cv::Mat data_mat(data.size(), 1, CV32FC1, &data[0]);  // ** Make 1 column Mat from vector

std::vector<int> labels;
std::vector<float> centers;
cv::kmeans(data_mat, 3, labels,     // ** Pass 1 column Mat from Mat to kmeans
   cv::TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER+CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 10, 0.1),
    3, cv::KMEANS_PP_CENTERS, centers);
```

Comment: In the end, both answers point to the same idea :-) Instead of reshaping I now just store my data directly in a matrix of appropriate dimensions and stopped using a vector.